# How to let Django serve images when hosting on Vercel

Tags: django, vercel, next.js13

I deployed a Django project on Vercel. The app is responsible for serving data to a Next.js frontend. However, the images don't get served while other data do. GET request to the images return NOT FOUND error after deploying to Vercel. I have studied all similar questions on this platform but none seems to solve my problem.

I have this in my settings.py file:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles_build', 'static')

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media/article_photos')
```

#### I'm serving only the article_photos.

I have this in my project urls.py file:

```
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

This is the structure of my media folder:

[image]

I have struggled with this problem throughout the whole day. Any help will be appreciated.

#### Update: This is my vercel.json file:

```
{
    "builds": [{
        "src": "core/wsgi.py",
        "use": "@vercel/python",
        "config": { "maxLambdaSize": "15mb", "runtime": "python3.9" }
    },
    {
        "src": "build_files.sh",
        "use": "@vercel/static-build",
        "config": { "distDir": "staticfiles_build" }
    }],
    "routes": [
        {
            "src": "/static/(.*)",
            "dest": "/static/$1"
        },
        {
            "src": "/(.*)",
            "dest": "core/wsgi.py"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my my build_files.sh

```
 echo "BUILD START"
 python3.9 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
 python3.9 manage.py collectstatic --noinput --clear
 echo "BUILD END"
```

#### Update 2: Below is the error returned:

> “/var/task/media/article_photos/2023/11/10/WhatsApp_Image_2023-10-31_at_4.39.45_PM.jpeg”
> does not exist

Comment: Can you share your vercel.json?

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question with vercel.json file.  Expecting your reply.

Comment: I have edited the question and included the error returned.